# Prove that $\frac{a + b + c}{b - a} > 3$ with $ab < b^2 < 4ca$.

Tags: inequality

> $a$, $b$, $c$ are three positives such that $ab < b^2 < 4ca$. Prove that $$\large \dfrac{a + b + c}{b - a} > 3.$$

I can't think of a way to get around this problem. Although I can see that based on the given condition, $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ has no roots, which adds almost no information whatsoever.

If you have written an answer below, thanks for that!

Comment: In the title, you have $b-a$ as the denominator, but it's $c-a$ in the body of your question. I'm guessing one of those is a typo.

Comment: So, this is equivalent to showing $\frac{2a+c}{b-a}>2\to2a+c>2b-2a\to\frac{4a+c}2>b$. But, by AM-GM, we know that $\frac{4a+c}2\geq\sqrt{4ac}>b$, so we are done.

Comment: @DonThousand : Why not writing it as an answer?

Comment: Eh, I don't really like answering qs anymore. I tend to get obsessive over rep-hunting, so I tend to avoid it.

Comment: Writing an answer helps me understand more about your thought process.

Comment: Eh fine, gimme a few

Comment: Well, I'm not forcing you to do so.

Comment: @DonThousand : It is not rep-hunting. People who use the board to look for answers should find the answers in the answers section and should not be 'forced' to browse comments. 
That's why I recommend writing answers instead of comments even if they are very short or very simple.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comments, here's how I would approach this question. Note that since $a,b,c>0$, $b>a\to b-a>0$. So, we know via the AM-GM inequality that
$$\frac{4a+c}2\geq\sqrt{4ac}>b$$$$4a+c>2b\to 2a+c>2b-2a$$$$\frac{2a+c}{b-a}>2$$$$1+\frac{2a+c}{b-a}>3$$$$\frac{a+b+c}{b-a}>3$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c>0$ for all real $x$ and

$a>0$ and $(b-a)>0$

put $x=-2,$ We get

$f(-2)
=4a-2b+c> 0\Rightarrow 2a+c>2(b-a)$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \frac{a+b+c}{b-a}=1+\frac{2a+c}{b-a}>1+2=3.$

Comment: +1, shortcut: $4a-2b+c>0 \iff a+b+c>3(b-a)$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle a+b+c>a+b+\frac{b^2}{4a}=\bigg(4a+\frac{b^2}{4a}\bigg)+b-3a\geq 3(b-a)$

$$\displaystyle \frac{a+b+c}{b-a}>3$$